# Story about worlds physically within other worlds, like layers of an onion

Tags: story-identification

The story took place on a "planet" constructed like a set of nesting dolls, with people living on the surface of each of the hundreds or thousands of concentric spheres.  There was some sort of AI gatekeeper intended to prevent travel between spheres, but the inhabitants had discovered how to disable it with a paradox.

Probably a short story, not a novel.  I read it 30 years ago when I was a teenager, but I think it's older than I am.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ian M. Bank's novel [Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_(novel)) takes place on a world like this, but it's a recently published novel, so it's definitely not the answer...

Comment: Just FYI, that's probably some variant of a Dyson Sphere. Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_spheres_in_popular_culture

Comment: Thanks, all. I'll try Kapp's and Stableford's books.

Answer (score 7):

That sounds like the [*Cageworld*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cageworld_series) series by [Colin Kapp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Kapp), though it's only 30 years old, so it's a bit recent for your description. The [plot summary](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2916634-search-for-the-sun) of the first book, *Search for the Sun* (also known as *Cageworld*) sounds right.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds similar to [*Asgard's Secret*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594142114) by Brian Stableford, which is the correct age (it was a short story, then a novel).

Comment: Originally a novel, apparently, *[Journey to the Center](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6704)*.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the novella "Ker-Plop" by Ted Reynolds, published 1979. 
It likely appeared in Analog or Asimov's magazine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ker-Plop

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get this accepted — that user has not returned since 2012.

Comment: Consider it just an addition to an interesting list. I had no idea there were this many stories about concentric worlds.

Comment: [*Asimov's* January 1979](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41243). You couldn't be bothered to look it up? Guess I'll save myself the bother of clicking on the upvote button.

Comment: Also, you didn't bother to tell us how it matches the OP's description. Does it have (1) a planet made of hundreds or thousands of concentric spheres (2) with an AI gatekeeper (3) which was disabled by a paradox? Am I going to have to find a copy of the story and read it myself to find out?

Comment: Where I looked it up, it didn't say where it had been published. I was going by memory. (1) Yes. (2) I don't recall. (3). I don't recall.